# Android/Java - prevent OutOfMemoryError by detecting free RAM left before allocating

Tags: java, android, memory, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

In my app I'm processing some files. Some of them may be huge. When a file that is too big to fit in memory is encountered, I want to skip it and politely explain this to the user, showing the partial results from the other files in the end. The files are read in with a `BufferedReader` which is discarded after use, no native stuff. I realize more memory than the file size may be needed to load it, so I'm checking if 3 times the file size is available.

The problem is that I can't find a way to detect the remaining available memory for the app and an `OutOfMemoryError` always occurs when loading some file. I've searched all over SO, but there is no clear-cut answer to this. Things I've tried without luck:

1)

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
```

This returns a huge number, several hundred megabytes, that is obviously well over the several-megabytes-per-app heap limit. Needless to say, the app crashes.

2)

```
Runtime info = Runtime.getRuntime();
long freeSize = info.freeMemory();
```

This number is usually around a few megabytes and looks correct, but an OutOfMemoryError still occurs if comparing the 3-times file size to it

3)

```
Runtime info = Runtime.getRuntime();
long freeSize = info.maxMemory() - info.totalMemory();
```

A bit larger than the above number, but still a crash occurs

4)

```
Debug.MemoryInfo mi = new Debug.MemoryInfo();
Debug.getMemoryInfo(mi);
```

I can't even make sense of the data inside this object, but I feel it is not going to be of use in this case

5)

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
long freeMem = activityManager.getMemoryClass()*1024*1024 - Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
```

Crash again.

6)

Calling

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

before each file read doesn't have any effect

The nature of the processing (regex matching) requires that the entire file is present in memory and cannot be loaded in chunks. This is because regexes need random-access character reads, which is not possible for text files because of varying charset encodings, at least not with acceptable performance.

So how can this seemingly simple task be achieved?

Comment: what are you "processing"

Comment: your app should use less memory ... there is no other way ... not always OOME means that there is no free memory ... it can be also fragmentation of the heap problem ...

Comment: @tyczj Regex searching, nothing special

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how can this seemingly simple task be achieved?

On Android 5.x, with ART, occasionally one of your approaches might work. On older versions of Android, and for apps that have been in the foreground for a bit on Android 5.x, none of your approaches will work, because you are misunderstanding the problem.

The problem is not that you are out of memory, despite the name of the error. The problem is that **there is no single block of free memory big enough to process the allocation request**, and you have reached the heap limit so we cannot allocate more RAM from the OS. That is because the Android garbage collector is not a compacting garbage collector, and so the heap can be fragmented. The exception to that is when running under ART, on Android 5.0+, the heap will be compacted (slowly) while your app is in the background.

AFAIK, there is no API in Android that will tell you how big of a block of memory you can allocate successfully.

Comment: Ouch! But doesn't that mean that any Android app, if it is not re-using 100% of its Java objects, will crash sooner or later?

Comment: @OrlinGeorgiev: No. The app may never need to get anywhere close to its heap limit. And Android terminates background processes to free up system RAM for other processes, meaning that when your app runs, there's a decent chance that it is starting from a fresh heap. That being said, `OutOfMemoryError` is *much* more common in Android than it is in traditional Java environments, due to the heap limit and the non-compacting GC.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, take a look at the developer guide from Google about [Managing Your Apps Memory](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) specifically the section labelled "Check how much memory you should use". The section says this in regards to determining your application's per device heap size and what can hopefully be safely allocated:

> You can call [getMemoryClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass()) to get an estimate of your app's available heap in megabytes. If your app tries to allocate more memory than is available here, it will receive an OutOfMemoryError.

Knowing your actual heap size for the given device can allow you to dynamically determine what the maximum file size you can allocate for the device.

Comment: This is approach 5) and it fails